# Sklearn StackingClassifier: Adding features as inputs to the final estimator

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am using pipelines and stacking classifiers to construct a classification pipeline. In my setup, I would like to pass some extra raw features to the final estimator, along with predictions of the previous level's models. Diagrammatically, this would like like below:

[image]

I would still like to leverage both pipelines (which I've used to set everything up except the adding of Feat x/y) and [StackingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html) to do this, since it handles training a stacked model end-to-end quite cleanly. However, I dont see an option to add raw features to the predictions of the previous "level"'s models. Is there a good way to do this?

Note: The features input to the final estimator are not the same as the features input to model 1 and model 2, so I'm not looking for the **pass_through=True** flag.

Comment: To the person who voted to close the question, It would be great if you could leave some feedback to help me improve it. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, has this worked for you? I feel like it could give weird results since the probabiltities generated by Model1/2 will be from [0,1] and the other features may or not may be.

Comment: Yes it worked well. You can take two approaches to handling the different scales -- either normalize the features input directly into the final estimator in an appropriate way or, use a final estimator insensitive to this difference (e.g. tree-based methods like RF, XGB, etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't available as a quick feature, but I can think of two ways to piece it together while still making use of the `StackingClassifier` automation.  Each one comes with some downsides.

## Make extra features into predictions

Make a dummy predictor, that "predicts" by just returning the input, and use that as a base estimator to get the extra features through to the meta-estimator.  Use `ColumnTransformer` to pick out either the base estimators' features or the passthrough features.

```py
from sklearn.base import ClassifierMixin, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class IdentityPassthrough(ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        return X

partial_passthrough = Pipeline([
    ('pass', ColumnTransformer([('pass', 'passthrough', ['x', 'y'])])),
    ('ident', IdentityPassthrough()),
])
base_features = ColumnTransformer([('pass', 'passthrough', ['a', 'b'])])

model = StackingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('pass', partial_passthrough),
        ('tree', Pipeline([('select', base_features), ('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier())])),
        ('knn', Pipeline([('select', base_features), ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier())])),
    ])

model.fit(X, y)
```

## Use passthrough and select out base features

Use a composite for the meta-estimator, that selects down the features to the predictions from the base estimators and the desired extra features.  This is a little worrisome, because you have to know you're getting the right order of columns (until sklearn finishes dealing with feature names).  I.e., in the below code, features 0 and 1 are the predicted probabilities (and if the stacking method weren't exclusively `predict_proba`, that would need to be 1 and 3 because of the negative class predictions!), and 4 and 5 are the targeted passthrough variables (which were indexed 2 and 3 in the original frame).

```py
base_features = ColumnTransformer([('pass', 'passthrough', ['mean radius', 'mean texture'])])

model = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=[
        ('tree', Pipeline([('select', base_features), ('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])),
        ('knn', Pipeline([('select', base_features), ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier())])),
    ],
    final_estimator=Pipeline([
        ('select', ColumnTransformer([('select', 'passthrough', [0, 1, 4, 5])])),
        ('model', LogisticRegression())
    ]),
    passthrough=True,
)

model.fit(X, y)
```

The model diagrams:

```html
<!-- style defs (common to the two exports from estimator_html_repr) -->
<style>div.sk-top-container {color: black;background-color: white;}div.sk-toggleable {background-color: white;}label.sk-toggleable__label {cursor: pointer;display: block;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0;padding: 0.2em 0.3em;box-sizing: border-box;text-align: center;}div.sk-toggleable__content {max-height: 0;max-width: 0;overflow: hidden;text-align: left;background-color: #f0f8ff;}div.sk-toggleable__content pre {margin: 0.2em;color: black;border-radius: 0.25em;background-color: #f0f8ff;}input.sk-toggleable__control:checked~div.sk-toggleable__content {max-height: 200px;max-width: 100%;overflow: auto;}div.sk-estimator input.sk-toggleable__control:checked~label.sk-toggleable__label {background-color: #d4ebff;}div.sk-label input.sk-toggleable__control:checked~label.sk-toggleable__label {background-color: #d4ebff;}input.sk-hidden--visually {border: 0;clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);height: 1px;margin: -1px;overflow: hidden;padding: 0;position: absolute;width: 1px;}div.sk-estimator {font-family: monospace;background-color: #f0f8ff;margin: 0.25em 0.25em;border: 1px dotted black;border-radius: 0.25em;box-sizing: border-box;}div.sk-estimator:hover {background-color: #d4ebff;}div.sk-parallel-item::after {content: "";width: 100%;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;flex-grow: 1;}div.sk-label:hover label.sk-toggleable__label {background-color: #d4ebff;}div.sk-serial::before {content: "";position: absolute;border-left: 1px solid gray;box-sizing: border-box;top: 2em;bottom: 0;left: 50%;}div.sk-serial {display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;background-color: white;}div.sk-item {z-index: 1;}div.sk-parallel {display: flex;align-items: stretch;justify-content: center;background-color: white;}div.sk-parallel-item {display: flex;flex-direction: column;position: relative;background-color: white;}div.sk-parallel-item:first-child::after {align-self: flex-end;width: 50%;}div.sk-parallel-item:last-child::after {align-self: flex-start;width: 50%;}div.sk-parallel-item:only-child::after {width: 0;}div.sk-dashed-wrapped {border: 1px dashed gray;margin: 0.2em;box-sizing: border-box;padding-bottom: 0.1em;background-color: white;position: relative;}div.sk-label label {font-family: monospace;font-weight: bold;background-color: white;display: inline-block;line-height: 1.2em;}div.sk-label-container {position: relative;z-index: 2;text-align: center;}div.sk-container {display: inline-block;position: relative;}</style>

<!-- First approach diagram: -->
<div class="sk-top-container"><div class="sk-container"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="a4c7712b-4e69-42ca-b31f-ecbe7b6d1d89" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="a4c7712b-4e69-42ca-b31f-ecbe7b6d1d89">StackingClassifier</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>StackingClassifier(estimators=[('pass',                 Pipeline(steps=[('pass',                         ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass',                                          'passthrough',                                          ['mean '                                          'perimeter',                                          'mean '                                          'area'])])),                         ('ident',                         <__main__.IdentityPassthrough object at 0x7f2bfbf1f358>)])),                ('tree',                 Pipeline(steps=[('select',                         ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass',                                          'passthrough',                                          ['mean '                                          'radius',                                          'mean '                                          'texture'])])),                         ('tree',                         DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])),                ('knn',                 Pipeline(steps=[('select',                         ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass',                                          'passthrough',                                          ['mean '                                          'radius',                                          'mean '                                          'texture'])])),                         ('knn',                         KNeighborsClassifier())]))])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><label>pass</label></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="c41ba408-2542-42cf-be5d-d2bdb1f7ca39" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="c41ba408-2542-42cf-be5d-d2bdb1f7ca39">pass: ColumnTransformer</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass', 'passthrough',                 ['mean perimeter', 'mean area'])])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="d71f311c-d151-402b-80a4-97fcb9464d8f" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="d71f311c-d151-402b-80a4-97fcb9464d8f">pass</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>['mean perimeter', 'mean area']</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="3e9e3a12-5622-4e56-9171-dbc690ca50d8" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="3e9e3a12-5622-4e56-9171-dbc690ca50d8">passthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>passthrough</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="b5753df0-b293-4aeb-bbdb-d9adc63b6ac8" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="b5753df0-b293-4aeb-bbdb-d9adc63b6ac8">IdentityPassthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre><__main__.IdentityPassthrough object at 0x7f2bfbf1f358></pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><label>tree</label></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="4952e340-a144-40cd-897b-dcdee029fecb" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="4952e340-a144-40cd-897b-dcdee029fecb">select: ColumnTransformer</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass', 'passthrough',                 ['mean radius', 'mean texture'])])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="7efbe86f-2262-4048-81fd-7c652803cf4f" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="7efbe86f-2262-4048-81fd-7c652803cf4f">pass</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>['mean radius', 'mean texture']</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="7ccdbf06-9312-4424-a74e-e1c56b3fbe88" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="7ccdbf06-9312-4424-a74e-e1c56b3fbe88">passthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>passthrough</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="3a2df016-3631-4cc6-960c-695466268875" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="3a2df016-3631-4cc6-960c-695466268875">DecisionTreeClassifier</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><label>knn</label></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="5aaa1a50-3954-43c0-802d-0679ecfaaa5f" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="5aaa1a50-3954-43c0-802d-0679ecfaaa5f">select: ColumnTransformer</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass', 'passthrough',                 ['mean radius', 'mean texture'])])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="836d9068-cfb3-4545-a714-6f349403d567" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="836d9068-cfb3-4545-a714-6f349403d567">pass</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>['mean radius', 'mean texture']</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="0c9e6b1f-0f96-4d6f-8efc-e3bada46d6a7" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="0c9e6b1f-0f96-4d6f-8efc-e3bada46d6a7">passthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>passthrough</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="56bfccc3-bca0-4d87-a377-a81913e4098c" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="56bfccc3-bca0-4d87-a377-a81913e4098c">KNeighborsClassifier</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>KNeighborsClassifier()</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="57737187-5f4c-4186-ad65-e68cecfe14e8" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="57737187-5f4c-4186-ad65-e68cecfe14e8">LogisticRegression</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>LogisticRegression()</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<!-- Second approach diagram: -->
<div class="sk-top-container"><div class="sk-container"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="034d2534-0d63-4319-bfbf-3b0a7117e00f" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="034d2534-0d63-4319-bfbf-3b0a7117e00f">StackingClassifier</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>StackingClassifier(estimators=[('tree',                 Pipeline(steps=[('select',                         ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass',                                          'passthrough',                                          ['mean '                                          'radius',                                          'mean '                                          'texture'])])),                         ('tree',                         DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])),                ('knn',                 Pipeline(steps=[('select',                         ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass',                                          'passthrough',                                          ['mean '                                          'radius',                                          'mean '                                          'texture'])])),                         ('knn',                         KNeighborsClassifier())]))],          final_estimator=Pipeline(steps=[('select',                           ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('select',                                           'passthrough',                                           [0,                                            1,                                            4,                                            5])])),                          ('model',                           LogisticRegression())]),          passthrough=True)</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><label>tree</label></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="50985202-3021-4333-877c-034e62c6e07a" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="50985202-3021-4333-877c-034e62c6e07a">select: ColumnTransformer</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass', 'passthrough',                 ['mean radius', 'mean texture'])])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="8132ce46-3e0b-42d2-b42b-f0a53d192c07" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="8132ce46-3e0b-42d2-b42b-f0a53d192c07">pass</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>['mean radius', 'mean texture']</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="e1970d86-b28e-41d0-8297-4d2ed67b4b50" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="e1970d86-b28e-41d0-8297-4d2ed67b4b50">passthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>passthrough</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="fafe6dec-d6a7-4c00-b561-17f3307e4bde" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="fafe6dec-d6a7-4c00-b561-17f3307e4bde">DecisionTreeClassifier</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><label>knn</label></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="8d608e7c-c318-4a67-a9b7-26995a77bcc6" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="8d608e7c-c318-4a67-a9b7-26995a77bcc6">select: ColumnTransformer</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pass', 'passthrough',                 ['mean radius', 'mean texture'])])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="12515389-377c-4fd1-9b50-cf0515dc1919" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="12515389-377c-4fd1-9b50-cf0515dc1919">pass</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>['mean radius', 'mean texture']</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="4fa202f1-74c0-47ba-b34d-dbc4e460eff9" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="4fa202f1-74c0-47ba-b34d-dbc4e460eff9">passthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>passthrough</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="0ac195fa-6584-4220-a00e-8da1dd09b5de" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="0ac195fa-6584-4220-a00e-8da1dd09b5de">KNeighborsClassifier</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>KNeighborsClassifier()</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item sk-dashed-wrapped"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="ede1e052-c7af-4bd3-9da9-2fcc69dd8c86" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="ede1e052-c7af-4bd3-9da9-2fcc69dd8c86">select: ColumnTransformer</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('select', 'passthrough', [0, 1, 4, 5])])</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-parallel"><div class="sk-parallel-item"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-label-container"><div class="sk-label sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="8ad23c33-3176-45c6-9504-98299d187eda" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="8ad23c33-3176-45c6-9504-98299d187eda">select</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>[0, 1, 4, 5]</pre></div></div></div><div class="sk-serial"><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="9fa0446e-ea2b-4c32-b32b-07c9b2643717" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="9fa0446e-ea2b-4c32-b32b-07c9b2643717">passthrough</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>passthrough</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sk-item"><div class="sk-estimator sk-toggleable"><input class="sk-toggleable__control sk-hidden--visually" id="450a759e-b194-4bf9-a92b-b296f6c9f527" type="checkbox" ><label class="sk-toggleable__label" for="450a759e-b194-4bf9-a92b-b296f6c9f527">LogisticRegression</label><div class="sk-toggleable__content"><pre>LogisticRegression()</pre></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

See the whole thing in action on the Wisconsin breast cancer dataset [in this notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SO63974211.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed, well-thought-out answer. Inheriting from ClassifierMixIn was the step i was missing! I dont see any downsides of this approach (do you have any in mind?) , and the second approach the main thing is keeping track of the column ordering.

Comment: No real downside, except the custom class.  I had been assuming you'd need to have a separate instance for each extra feature, which was the downside I had in mind, but it turns out nothing in the StackingClassifier checks whether your base estimators return lots of columns.

Comment: @BenReiniger I am facing an issue with this resolution when using predict_proba inplace of predict with custom classifier. Please see details at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148145/sklearn-pipeline-one-feature-automatically-missed-out. Probably you will know the resolution. Thanks!