# Stacking classifier: Using custom classifier returns error

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm using a StackingClassifier in sklearn, where I want the component models to be custom classifiers. In order to do this, I wanted to test it out with some dummy code where the custom classifier is the exact same as an already existing model (KNN, in this example). However this throws an error, and I'm not sure I understand why, and looking for help with this. It's probably something fairly obvious (I'm new to trying to write custom classifiers and using ClassiferMixIn), but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing:

**Code -- the baseline example without my custom class (works):**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

model = StackingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('tree', Pipeline([('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])),
        ('knn', Pipeline([('knn', KNeighborsClassifier())])),
    ])

model.fit(X, y)
```

**Code -- the with my custom class (doesn't work):**

```
class MyOwnClassifier(ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self,classifier):
        self.classifier = classifier
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.classifier.fit(X,y)
        return self 
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.classifier.predict(X)
    
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return self.classifier.predict_proba(X)

model = StackingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('tree', Pipeline([('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42))])),
        ('knn', Pipeline([('knn', MyOwnClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()))])),
    ])

model.fit(X, y)
```

returns the error

```
AttributeError: 'MyOwnClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

What really puzzles me about this is that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974211/sklearn-stackingclassifier-adding-features-as-inputs-to-the-final-estimator) answer, an identity transform could be used as part of the pipeline, and I can't imagine that object had '*classes_*' either.

Comment: Unwave one of the working classifier in the code without your customer classifier `clf`, e.g `knn`. Print out `clf.classes_` which is assigned after fit. Now add attribute `self.classes_ = ...` in your custom classifier. Or perhaps you need to inherit a class that will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 3 problems with your code:

1. `StackingClassifier` expects an attribute `classes_` to be available on a fitted classifier, which is clearly stated in the error message. The linked example does have it, whereas yours doesn't. It can be checked if you run like `dir(MyOwnClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()).fit(X,y))`.
2. `BaseEstimator` is missing from your class definition (you can do without it, but its presence makes life easier)
3. `Pipelines` in you code are extraneous clutter that are not necessary to debug your code and only complicating debugging.

Once you correct these problems you have a working code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.base import ClassifierMixin, BaseEstimator

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

class MyOwnClassifier(ClassifierMixin, BaseEstimator):
    
    def __init__(self,classifier):
        self.classifier = classifier
        
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.classifier.fit(X,y)
        self.classes_ = self.classifier.classes_
        return self
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.classifier.predict(X)
    
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return self.classifier.predict_proba(X)

model = StackingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)),
        ('knn', MyOwnClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()))])

model.fit(X,y)
StackingClassifier(estimators=[('tree',
                                DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)),
                               ('knn',
                                MyOwnClassifier(classifier=KNeighborsClassifier()))])
```

Comment: Thank you. Probably silly question, but why does having BaseEstimator make my life easier here?

Comment: Try without it and see the methods you have to define yourself