# How to use different feature set on for each estimator in a Multi estimator sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

Below is an example sklearn pipeline. There are two sklearn StackingClassifiers:

1. stackingclassifier1 with base classifier as RandomForestClassifier & stackingclassifier2 as Meta Learner.
2. stackingclassifier2 with base classifier as KNearestNeighborsClassifier & SVC as Meta Learner.

So pipeline is:
[image]
I want to use featureset1 on RndomForestClassifier & featureset2 on KNearestNeighborsClassifier & featureset3 on SVM. However on pipeline only option I am getting is to pass one featureset for all pipeline steps - Pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train).

How could I pass different featureset to different estimators
[image]

Also this is a workaround implementation. In my design there is no stack. Just one learner passing probability to next. Then get final probabilities at last step. If there is a better implementation technique using pipeline please add that as well. Thanks

Comment: You can probably use a `ColumnTransformer` to handle the different feature sets.  But the rest of this setup doesn't make much sense: stackingclassifiers with only one base estimator are unlikely to be useful, and the first stack will be treated as a transformer, and so will only pass the RF predictions forward to the next step (the LR will be ignored entirely).

Comment: @BenReiniger Your point is absolutely correct. I realized that the example I have posted is flawed. I have fixed that now & have provided detailed information on what I am looking for in the description. Have a look. I will try out ColumnTransformer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63974211/10495893

Comment: @BenReiniger This is really great trick will be interesting to implement this.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BenReiniger I am facing an issue with this resolution when using predict_proba inplace of predict with custom classifier. Please see details at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148145/sklearn-pipeline-one-feature-automatically-missed-out. Probably you will know the resolution. Thanks!