# Sklearn Pipeline: One feature automatically missed out

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

I created a Custom Classifier(Dummy Classifier). Below is definition. I also added some print statements & global variables to capture values

```
class FeaturePassThroughClassifier(ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y):
        global test_arr1
        self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
        test_arr1 = X
        print("1:", X.shape)
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        global test_arr2
        test_arr2 = X
        print("2:", X.shape)
        return X   
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        global test_arr3
        test_arr3 = X
        print("3:", X.shape)
        return X
```

Below is Stacking Classifier definition where the above defined CustomClassifier is one of base classifier. There are 3 more base classifiers (these are fitted estimators). Goal is to get input training set variables as is (which will come out from CustomClassifier) + prediction from base_classifier2, base_classifier3, base_classifier4. These features will act as input to meta classifier.

```
model = StackingClassifier(estimators=[
    ('select_features', Pipeline(steps = [("model_feature_selector", ColumnTransformer([('feature_list', 'passthrough', X_train.columns)])),
                                             ('base(dummy)_classifier1', FeaturePassThroughClassifier())])),
                                    ('base_classifier2', base_classifier2),
                                    ('base_classifier3', base_classifier3),
                                    ('base_classifier4', base_classifier4)
],
                                     final_estimator = Pipeline(memory=None,
    steps=[
        ('save_base_estimator_output_data', FunctionTransformer(save_base_estimator_output_data, validate=False)),  ('final_model', RandomForestClassifier())
    ], verbose=True), passthrough = False, **stack_method = 'predict_proba'**)
```

Below is o/p on fitting the model. There are 230 variables:
[image]

**Here is the problem:** There are 230 variables but CustomClassifier o/p is showing only 229 which is strange. We can clearly see from print statements above that 230 variables get passed through CustomClassifier.

[image]

I need to use stack_method = "predict_proba". I am not sure what's going wrong here. The code works fine when stack_method = "predict".

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a binary classifier, the classifier class expects you to add two probability columns in the output matrix - one for probability for class label "1" and another for "0".
In the output, it has dropped one of these since both are not required, hence, 230 columns get reduced to 229. Add a dummy column to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the Notes section of the documentation:

> When `predict_proba` is used by each estimator (i.e. most of the time for `stack_method='auto'` or specifically for `stack_method='predict_proba'`), The first column predicted by each estimator will be dropped in the case of a binary classification problem.

[Here's the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/98cf537f5c538fdbc9d27b851cf03ce7611b8a48/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py#L133) that eliminates the first column.

You could add a sacrificial first column in your custom estimator's `predict_proba`, or switch to `decision_function` (which will cause differences depending on your real base estimators), or use the `passthrough` option instead of the custom estimator (doing feature selection in the `final_estimator` object instead).

Answer (score 1):

Both the above solutions are on point. This is how I implemented the workaround with dummy column:

**Declare a custom transformer whose output is the column that gets dropped due reasons explained above:**

```
class add_dummy_column(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print(type(X))
        return X[[self.key]]
```

Do a feature union where above customer transformer + column transformer are called to create final dataframe. This will duplicate the column that gets dropped. Below is altered definition for defining Stacking classifier with FeatureUnion:

```
model = StackingClassifier(estimators=[
    ('select_features', Pipeline(steps = [('featureunion', FeatureUnion([('add_dummy_column_to_input_dataframe', add_dummy_column(key='FEATURE_THAT_GETS_DROPPED')), 
                                            ("model_feature_selector", ColumnTransformer([('feature_list', 'passthrough', X_train.columns)]))])),
                                             ('base(dummy)_classifier1', FeaturePassThroughClassifier())])),
                                    ('base_classifier2', base_classifier2),
                                    ('base_classifier3', base_classifier3),
                                    ('base_classifier4', base_classifier4)
],
                                     final_estimator = Pipeline(memory=None,
    steps=[
        ('save_base_estimator_output_data', FunctionTransformer(save_base_estimator_output_data, validate=False)),  ('final_model', RandomForestClassifier())
    ], verbose=True), passthrough = False, **stack_method = 'predict_proba'**)
```